# For loop in jquery . I need to run scripts for 20 time each with with increment

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have no idea about loop in jquery. I want the following code to be run as for loop from product1 to product20 and check the same if quantity1 to quantity20 have no value then set it to 1.

```
$('#product1').change(function() {
    if(  $('#quantity1').val().length == 0 ){
        $('#quantity1').val("1");
    }
});

$('#product2').change(function() {
    if(  $('#quantity2').val().length == 0 ){
        $('#quantity2').val("1");
    }
});
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Use the same class on all 20 elements and use that as the selector, then you don't need to use a loop.

Comment: Have you tried `.each(...)`? Loops such as `for(i = 0; i <....)` are almost never the best way to do something in high-level code.

Comment: @WillPalmer `$.each()` uses a for loop.

Comment: What is your `#product`, a textbox or what ?

Comment: @WillPalmer `for` loops are more than [80%+ faster](http://jsperf.com/jquery-each-vs-for-loop/115) than `$.each(...)`. Sounds like a good reason to use them to me!

Comment: @ahren: You need the anonymous function to create a closure anyway, so I think that the performance difference is minimal.

Comment: @ahren: And if you're in a situation where you *need* to optimise something, one generally switches to using low-level code. In high-level code, `for` loops are almost never correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that the `each` method is the best solution here, as you need an anonymous function anyway to create a closuse that holds the value for each iteration (as the event handler runs later, each one needs its own version of the loop counter):

```
$.each(new Array(20), function(i){
  $('#product' + (i+1)).change(function() {
    var q = $('#quantity' + (i+1));
    if (q.val().length == 0 ){
      q.val("1");
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try this to add event handler for all inputs whose `id` begins with `product`

```
$('input[id^="product"]').change(function() {
    var len=$(this).attr('id').length;
    var q='#quantity'+$(this).attr('id').substr(7);
    if($(q).val().length == 0 ){
        $(q).val(1);
    }
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/iximur/5/edit).

Comment: That will change the value of the product field, not the corresponding quantity field.

Comment: The `substr(len-1)` gives you the last character of the id, so from `"product20"` you will get `"0"`. You would use `substr(7)` to get the whole number.

Answer (score 0):

Read [this](http://api.jquery.com/each/) for more information on loops in jquery.

Use starts with selector for selecting your controls. Read [this](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) for details.

You can use a jQuery function as below :

```
$('input[id^="product"]').each(function(index) {
$(this).change(function() {
            if(  $(this).val().length == 0 ){
                $(this).val("1");
            }
});
}
```

Comment: That will change the value of the product field, not the corresponding quantity field.

Comment: Yes, thought of it later and found that @Sheikh Heera, has already posted a correct version. So left as it is.

Answer (score 0):

just use normal Java script for loop

```
for (i=0; i<5; i++)
{
  $('#product'+i).change(function() {
    if(  $('#quantity'+i).val().length == 0 ){
        $('#quantity'+i).val("1");
    }
});
}
```

Comment: That will capture the loop counter in the closure, so when the change event happens it will always be `5`. When you edit any product, it will try to check the value of `#quantity5`, which doesn't exist.